# php problem with function and eval on array

Tags: php, eval

I have function:

```
function selects($sql,$tmpl) {

preg_match_all('/{[^}]*}/', $tmpl, $m);

foreach($m[0] as $key => $val) {
$find[] = $val;
$replace[] = '$row[\''.str_replace(array('{','}'),"",$val).'\']';
}

eval($replace);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$selects .= str_replace($find, $replace, $tmpl)."\n";
}

return $selects;

}

echo selects($country_sql,'<option value="{id}">{name}</option>');
```

It outputs:

```
<option value="$row['id']">$row['name']</option>
```

It should output:

```
<option value="1">something</option>
<option value="2">something</option>
...
```

Any ideas ?

I wrote this function because I have many different selects and I need different templates for them.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all? You need to think about what you are trying to accomplish. `eval` is not necessary here

Comment: Instead of replacing the template with PHP code, why not just replace with the value directly, i.e., `str_replace($find, $row[$replace], $tmpl)` and populate $replace with the field names rather than PHP code.

Comment: if `$country_sql` is a sql statement you're missing the `$res = mysql_query($country_sql)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me considering `$country_sql` is a sql statement

```
<?php
function selects($sql,$template) {
    preg_match_all('/{([^}]*)}/', $template, $matches);
    $result = mysql_query($sql); //were missing this?
    $select = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $aux = $template;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++){
            $aux = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $row[$matches[1][$i]],$aux);
        }
        $select .= $aux."\n";
    }
    return $select;
}

echo "<select>";
echo selects($country_sql,'<option value="{id}">{name}</option>');
echo "</select>";
?>
```

You could add the `<select>` part to the function but that's up to you.

Comment: Yes it works thanks, no need mysql_query in function because I already sending mysql array to function in $sql variable.