# Replace string at particular position in function In PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to Print some dynamically data from my function to passing string in function like this.

**My Function**

```
function mysql_funX_Repeter($query,$itemtemplet)
{
    $this->mysql_funX_connect();

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Repeter Query Error.");
    if (!$result) 
    {
        $message = 'ERROR:' . mysql_error();
        return $message;
    }
    else
    {
        $newtempelt = str_replace("Eval", '$row', $itemtemplet);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

            echo $newtempelt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Passing Value In Function**

```
<ul>
<?php
$rptvalue="<li><a href=''>Eval['name']</a></li>";
$myFun->mysql_funX_Repeter("Select name from tbldemo",$rptvalue);
?>
</ul>
```

**My Output**

- $row['name']
- $row['name']
- $row['name']

**I want Output**

- raj
- ram
- prince

But it's Show me only variable but not show it's database value.
How to solve this...!!!

Comment: I'm not sure why this is, I suspect it is a safeguard. Here's a simpler usage case. `$row['name'] = 'test';
$rptvalue="<li><a href=''>Eval['name']</a></li>";
echo str_replace("Eval", '$row', $rptvalue);`

Comment: No, sir It's Can't Work. It's Show like `$row['name']`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this behavior and haven't been able to find any documentation on it. The code I posted is a simpler form of your code to demonstrate the issue; so others that come here can reproduce the issue quicker and might know the cause.

Comment: Really you should try to avoid the mysql_ function as they are depreciated [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1). 

The answer to this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574437/php-problem-with-function-and-eval-on-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574437/php-problem-with-function-and-eval-on-array) Shows a way of doing what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I would change a little bit your method.

```
function mysql_funX_Repeter($query,$itemtemplet)
{
    $this->mysql_funX_connect();

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Repeter Query Error.");
    if (!$result) 
    {
        $message = 'ERROR:' . mysql_error();
        return $message;
    }
    else
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {

            echo "<li><a href=''>".$row[$itemtemplet]."</a></li>";
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, your method invokation:

```
<ul>
<?php
$rptvalue="name";
$myFun->mysql_funX_Repeter("Select ".$rptvalue." from tbldemo",$rptvalue);
?>
</ul>
```

And that's how I'd do it to avoid nasty evals. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function mysql_funX_Repeter($query,$itemtemplet)
 {
  $html='';
  $this->mysql_funX_connect();
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Repeter Query Error.");
  $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
  if($num_rows){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $newtempelt = str_replace("Eval", $row['column_name'], $itemtemplet);
        $html.="<li><a href=''>".$newtempelt."</a></li>";
    }
  }
  return $html;  
}
```

//calling method mysql_funX_Repeter

```
<ul>
<?php
$rptvalue="name";
echo $myFun->mysql_funX_Repeter("Select ".$rptvalue." from tbldemo",$rptvalue);
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Developer My Problem Was Solved.
Thanks for Reply.

**My Function**

```
//This Repeter Function Created By Priyank Patel
function mysql_funX_Repeter($query,$itemtemplet)
{
    $this->mysql_funX_connect();

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Repeter Query Error.");
    if (!$result) 
    {
        $message = 'ERROR:' . mysql_error();
        return $message;
    }
    else
    {
        preg_match_all('/{([^}]*)}/', $itemtemplet, $matches);
        $select = '';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $aux = $itemtemplet;

            for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++){
                $aux = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $row[$matches[1][$i]],$aux);
            }
            $select .= $aux."\n";
        }
        mysql_close();
        return $select;
    }
}
```

**Calling Style**

```
<ul><?php $templet="<li>{name}</li>";echo $myFun->mysql_funX_Repeter("Select * from tbldemo",$templet);?></ul>
```